# regex to not match when string between two strings

Tags: python, regex

I have the following parsing scenario in python, there is cases of lines:

1. `{{ name xxxxxxCONTENTxxxxx /}}`
2. `{{ name }} xxxxxxxCONTENTxxxxxxx {{ name /}}`
3. `{{ name xxxxxxCONTENTxxx {comand} xxxxCONTENTxxx /}}`

All I need to do is classify to which case the given line belongs using regex.

I can successfully classify between 1) and 2) but having trouble to deal with 3).

to catch 1) I use:

```
re.match('\s*{{[^{]*?/}}\s*',line)
```

to catch 2) I use:

```
re.match('{{.*?}}',line)
```

and then raise a flag to keep the context since case 2) can be over multiple lines. How can I catch case 3) ??

The condition which I'm currently trying to match is to test for:

```
- start with '{{'
- end with '/}}'
- with no '{{' in between
```

However I'm having a hard time phrasing this in regex.

Comment: '^{{((?!{{).)*/}}$' - See [Regular expression to match line that doesn't contain a word?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)

Comment: This works well in js but having trouble with it in python. In js it catches condition 1 and 2 which is good,  but in python it gives no match.

Comment: Using http://pythex.org/ (great site btw :) ) I get that the regex matches 1 and 3, but not 2 - because it has '{{' in it.
Could you post your code that didn't work?

Comment: Maybe [`{{(?:(?!{{).)*/}}`](https://regex101.com/r/jB1vM5/3)? (maybe `re.DOTALL` is necessary if it spans across multiple lines)

Comment: Could you please narrow your question to what you exactly need to match and what not to match? Do you want to match `{{ name xxxxxxCONTENTxxxxx /}}` and `{{ name xxxxxxCONTENTxxx {comand} xxxxCONTENTxxx /}}` as entire strings, and not match at all `{{ name }} xxxxxxxCONTENTxxxxxxx {{ name /}}`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think OP is just trying to classify a string in 3 options

Comment: @rock321987: You know that regexes do not "classify", they either match or not. That is what we need to understand to answer the question. Else, we can only guess.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Maybe he is trying to `match` and then `classify`

Comment: @rock321987: See, you are guessing :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes I am..:)

Comment: @GerrievanWyk: [`^{{(?:(?!{{|/}}).)*/}}$`](https://regex101.com/r/mG0oI6/2)? Or even `(?s)^{{(?:(?!{{|/}}).)*/}}$`?

Comment: I'm classifying by checking match with if statements. Sorry for the confusion.  The following worked for me in python to catch condition 1 and 3 : \s*{{((?!{{).)*?/}}\s* .. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The conditions:

```
- start with '{{'
- end with '/}}'
- with no '{{' in between
```

are a perfect fit for a [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed).

```
^{{(?:(?!{{|/}}).)*/}}$
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bM4mL1/1).

The `(?:(?!{{|/}}).)*` matches any text that is not `{{` and `/}}` (thus matches up to the first `/}}`). Anchors (`^` and `$`) allow to only match a whole string that starts with `{{` and ends with `/}}` and has no `{{` inside. Note that with `re.match`, you do not neet `^` anchor.

Now, **to only match the 3rd type of strings**, you need to specify that your pattern should have `{....}`:

```
^{{(?:(?!{{|/}}).)*{[^{}]*}(?:(?!{{|/}}).)*/}}$
   | ----  1 -----|| - 2 -||--------1-----|
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mG0oI6/3)

Part 1 is the tempered greedy token described above and `{[^{}]*}` matches a single `{...}` substring making it compulsory inside the input.